# Properly signed phpmailer emails keep being marked as spam or get rejected

Tags: php, ubuntu, postfix-mta, spf, dkim

For the past 2 months I have been struggling with the mailserver for a webapplication I'm building. Mails kept being marked as spam or didn't even arrive at a recipient at all.

I started researching this fairly common problem and found out about all the things that come with signing email en authenticating mailservers and so on. I even had to move my domain name to another hosting provider just so I could setup my dkim, spf and dmarc records correctly.

After doing all of this [mail-tester](https://www.mail-tester.com/) gave me the following results:
[image: mail-tester results]

I figured this would be good enough so I started testing some more. Only to find out that gmail still marks my emails as spam, and outlook (hotmail etc.) still doesn't even receive the email's in any folder.

Since I don't know what to try anymore, i am hopeful someone here would have some suggestions for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Gmail will usually say why they classified your message as spam in their headers. If you're using PHPMailer, set `SMTPDebug = 2` and you can watch the delivery to outlook to be sure it's being accepted. Other than that, spam filters are notoriously inaccurate - gmail will typically put *everything* in spam by default even if the message is perfectly formatted, and you have no recourse, other than saying "not spam" and hoping it doesn't do it next time. It's why I don't use gmail...

Answer (score 2):

That mail tester is really basic it doesn't give you a realistic picture of whats really going on.

You should test with the one from [Unlock The Inbox](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/mail-tester/).  It does well over 400+ different checks, depending on what you have configured.